# Remove telephone from Skype conversation

Tags: skype

How do I remove a telephone from a Skype conversation?

At work we have a permanent Skype conversation for our development group ("Dev chat"). It's primarily used for text conversation but in the past we have used it for voice conferences too. Once Skype wasn't working properly on one of my colleague's machine so we added his land line to the conversation and we have not been able to remove it since then.

I am aware of the `/kick` command as detailed in the [Skype chat command help page](https://support.skype.com/en-us/faq/FA10042/What-are-chat-commands-and-roles), but that requires a Skype user name which doesn't apply to the telephone.

We are no longer at the office to which the telephone number belongs so it would be good to get rid of it. Note that having the telephone there causes no actual problems with the conversation, but it just looks odd.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

/kick phonenumber should do it. We just tried it from one of our chat sessions and it worked.

Comment: Thanks for that! The problem was I didn't actually have kick privileges in that chat and Skype unhelpfully doesn't give an error message. It's a three year old conversation and I thought I had created it but apparently not. Got myself MASTER privilege and `/kick number` worked.

Comment: Care to explain why that works?